# php шифр вернама, подглючивает вычисление

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

ввожу в word1 word2 нули и единицы, xor-ю их, и вывожу в result
по нажатии decrypt должны xor иться word2 и result, оно иногда работает нормально, а иногда значения ячеек сами меняются

```html
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $Word1 = $_POST['Word1'];
    $Word2 = $_POST['Word2'];
    $result = $_POST['result'];
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < strlen($Word1)) {
        if ($Word1{$i} == $Word2{$i}) {
            $result = $result . "0";
        } else {
            $result = $result . "1";
        }
        $i++;
    }
}


if ($_POST['Erase']) {
    $result = "";
    $Word1 = "";
    $Word2 = "";
    $Decrypt = "";
}


if ($_POST['Decrypt']) {
    $Word2 = $_POST['Word2'];
    $result = $_POST['result'];

    $j = 0;
    while ($j < strlen($Word2)) {
        if ($Word2{$j} == $result{$j}) {
            $Decrypt = $Decrypt . "0";
        } else {
            $Decrypt = $Decrypt . "1";
        }
        $j++;
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <br/>word1<br/>
    <textarea rows="1" cols="100" name="Word1"><?= $Word1 ?></textarea>

    <br/><br/>word2<br/>
    <textarea rows="1" cols="100" name="Word2"><?= $Word2 ?></textarea>

    <br/><br/>result<br/>
    <textarea rows="1" cols="100" name="result"><?= $result ?></textarea>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit"value="Convert">
    <input type="submit" name="Erase" value="Erase">
    <input type="submit" name="Decrypt" value="Decrypt">

    <br/><br/>Decrypt<br/>
    <textarea rows="1" cols="100" name="result"><?= $Decrypt ?></textarea>
    <br/>

</form>
```

Comment: А какой смысл в неработающем сниппете?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` `if(isset($_POST['Erase']))` `if(isset($_POST['Decrypt']))`